# ImageView won't initialized in view pager

Tags: android

I'm trying to create Intro Slider for users so they can better understand the concept of application, but i have problems in initializing image view inside view pager.

Here i'm setting layouts to view pager and setting parameters to it's layout:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

        Picasso.with(WelcomeActivity.this)
                .load(imageResources[position])
                .into(imageView);

        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }
```

I have three layouts and three image views, but ImageView won't initialized and i can't set image resources to it. Images are not showing in image views and i'm getting no errors. What i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there anything in logcat?

Comment: Nothing worth mentioning.

Comment: try using Picasso.with(WelcomeActivity.this).load(url).into(new Target() { ... }); instead and check if you get any call to onBitmapFailed or onBitmapLoaded.